# How to position ViewPager above RecyclerView?

Tags: android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

This xml layout has been populated by `ViewPager` and `RecyclerView` via an activity class, I want to position `ViewPager` on top and `RecyclerView` at the  bottom, I tired to use `android:layout_below="@+id/awesomepager"` in the `LinearLayout` of  `RecyclerView` but it doesn't work (it stays on top behind the toolbar[Deep blue color in the picture]), I also used `android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/awesomepager"` but that puts it inside the `ViewPager` at the bottom.

I basically want `ViewPager` and `RecyclerView` to be siblings , like this picture , black area to be `ViewPager` at the top and the green area to be `RecyclerView` at the bottom.

[image]

**what is correct way to do this?**

***viewpager_with_toolbar_overlay.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/awesomepager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="#068006"
            android:layout_below="@+id/awesomepager"
            >

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/episodesLIST"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_layout" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**Update:**

If I define the hight of ViewPager the problem will be resolved , but when screen size changes lower part of the screen will be blank

Answer (score 0):

I searched a lot and finally came up with a solution, first I changed `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` and added `android:orientation="vertical"` to it,  then added `android:layout_weight="1"` to `ViewPager`.

**Final version**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/awesomepager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="#068006"
            android:layout_below="@+id/awesomepager"
            >

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/episodesLIST"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_layout" />

</FrameLayout>
```